# Apache MINA - stuck on SSL connection

Tags: ssl, freeze, apache-mina

I am having troubles with Apache MINA core library.
When I deploy my application to a remote server some of the requests are not processed (around 2%). It looks like there might be a problem with SSL.

Log tail: http://pastebin.com/48bwWsjs
When request is not being processed, it is always stuck on the:

```
org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter  - Session Server[40](ssl...): Processing the SSL Data
```

Did something similar happened to any of you?

I tried Apache-mina 2.0.7 and 2.0.16

Env:

```
bash-4.2$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

bash-4.2$ uname -a
Linux 8d9ad913fa03 4.4.39-34.54.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 30 19:11:28 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: almost got the exact same issue. from my research, i guess its something to do with dns lookup. and that sometimes takes too much time.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you found the solution?